# WordPress 5 upgrade: until when is it safe to keep project running in 4.x?

Tags: plugins, themes, upgrade

As announced, Wordpress version 5 will be hitting the road this December. Considering the availability of security support and patches for previous versions (4.9.x, 4.8.x, 4.7.x), until when is it considered safe to postpone the 5.x upgrade and keep projects running in 4.x?

Comment: Why do you need to postpone it? If you don't want the new editor just install the Classic Editor plugin.

Comment: I have read version 5 could be more disruptive than usual updates and maybe not backwards compatible in some aspects, but I should maybe dig deeper into that.

Comment: Only in regards to the editor, which is addressed by the Classic Editor plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Supported_Versions):

> The only current officially supported version is WordPress 4.9.8.
>   Previous major releases before this may or may not get security
>   updates as serious exploits are discovered.

And it has always been that way - only one version is officially supported.

This means it's always a bad idea to postpone updates.

So if you're afraid of Gutenberg, then you should:

1. Prepare a test version for your site and check if it will cause any problems with 5.0.
2. Disable Gutenberg, if you don't want to use it.

You can disable Gutenberg with this code:

```
if (version_compare($GLOBALS['wp_version'], '5.0-beta', '>')) {
    // WP > 5 beta
    add_filter('use_block_editor_for_post_type', '__return_false', 100);
} else {
    // WP < 5 beta
    add_filter('gutenberg_can_edit_post_type', '__return_false');
}
```

or using one of available plugins.

Comment: Hum, thanks for your comment on this. I assume for now it would be better to disable Gutemberg as suggested. Would you say Gutemberg is the sole disruptive change on WP 5, or are there other areas of concern when upgrading? Thank you!

Comment: Gutenberg is main reason for postponing the update, I guess. It’s not bad, but the timing is really awful...